# Created object isn't being saved. Pass by reference

Tags: c++, oop, instance

I'm trying to add a Player to a factory in this example. I'm fairly new to pointers and don't get what I'm doing wrong.

in my factory class I have:

```
void Factory::addPlayer(const Player& player)
{
    m_player.push_back(player);
}
```

and in the program I'm trying to add it as such:

```
Factory* fact = new Factory();

Player* c = new Player(1, 2, 100, "Name");

fact->addPlayer(*c);
```

However, when I debug, the 'c' instance is unchanged.

Have I not referenced properly? If anyone could help or point in the right direction I would appreciate any help.

Comment: In what way do you expect it to have changed?

Comment: In order to point you in the right direction, you should explain what you want to do with the elements of the vector. For instance, why do you care if `c` is "unchanged"?

Comment: Well I'm trying to add 'c' to a list of m_player in Factory or 'fact' as I've shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that an `std::vector` holds values, not references or pointers. So when you do this:

```
 m_player.push_back(player);
```

the vector stores its own copy of the `Player` passed to it. Once you have done that, no action taken on the elements of the vector should affect whatever `c` points to.